# How to change orientation rotation timing in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, screen-orientation, screen-rotation

How to change orientation rotation timing in Windows Phone 8.1?
This time delay exactly called as (probability `VisualState` transition)?
Can I set time delay at Page level or Application level and how?

Comment: Please add comment if question isn't clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not Api or Documentation available to access the system animations (like theme transitions too).

**So the simple answer is: No you can not.**

The long hard workaround would be to catch the screen orientation by yourself and handle the orientation change via an own animation (in a Storyboard for example). The drawback is, that the Appbar and Statusbar would not rotate with the page.